# Retrofit with Moshi - convert JsonArray to String

Tags: android, retrofit2, moshi

Below I prepared some of the code I use when I execute query to server.

Response from the server returns list with books in json format. One of the fields `params` contains list in json array.

How could I force Moshi to treat this field as a raw string?

Here is an explanation of my code.

This is a pseudo-class from where I call instance of Retrofit.

```
public final class RestApi {
    private static final String API_ENDPOINT_KEY = "...";
    private final MyApi myApi;

    private RestApi() {
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        OkHttpClient client = builder.build();

        final Retrofit retrofit = (new Retrofit.Builder())
                .baseUrl(API_ENDPOINT_KEY)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        myApi = retrofit.create(MyApi.class);
    }

    public static RestApi getInstance() {
        return RestApiGazeta.InstanceHolder.INSTASNCE;
    }

    private static final class InstanceHolder {
        private static final RestApi INSTASNCE = new RestApi();
    }
}
```

This is the Book class with prepared fields for Moshi.

```
@Generated("com.robohorse.robopojogenerator")
public class Book{

    @Json(name = "pages")
    private int pages;

    @Json(name = "params")
    private Params params;

}
```

This is the query for Retrofit for querying list of books.

```
@GET("android/getBooks.json")
Call<List<Book>> getBooks(
        @Query("section") String section
);
```

What I have tried was I changed return type in Book class type `Params` to `String` but I was returning exception about `Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at path $[0].params`.

Comment: Is this what you're asking for? https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/318
subscribe to the issue.

Comment: it'd be interesting to hear why you'd like this functionality. normally, types are composed of other types, instead of mixing types and JSON.

Comment: @EricCochran imagine You must store huge json reponse to sqlite but put them to single table. So nested params would be flattened and stored to single column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I've read Moshi documentation and it seems to be easy to convert any field to json string. I don't know how to parse it on the fly but here is the solution how to do it after You get ready (in my case) `Book` object.

```
Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
JsonAdapter<Params> jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(Params.class);
String json = jsonAdapter.toJson(body.getParams());
```

That's it.